# jQuery File Upload - Params inline in input

Tags: parameters, jquery-file-upload

I have 2 Jquery File Upload Inputs. I would like to send the type of each that I expect.

For example:

`<input id="image" class="fileupload" name="image3" maxfilesize="500000" data-url="/_uploader/gallery/upload" autoupload="1" type="file" mime="jpeg">`

and

`<input id="image" class="fileupload" name="image3" maxfilesize="500000" data-url="/_uploader/gallery/upload" autoupload="1" type="file" mime="pdf">`

How can I send parameters inline? I can't receive "mime" property.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, is with data-form-data={'some':'thing'}